# Clone postgres table including indexes and data

Tags: postgresql, performance

I need to clone a Postgres table. This must include all data, indexes constraints, all aspects of the scehema.

I have been dropping and creating the table, however due to the size of the table this is very time consuming.

Is it possible to do this in one statement?

```
 CREATE TABLE "dbHelper"."tmp_manual_forwarding" (LIKE "dbHelper"."tmp_manual" INCLUDING ALL) AS
SELECT * FROM "dbHelper"."tmp_manual"
```

Comment: The best option is `pg_dump` and restore the dump.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy all constraints etc by running the below code but you may need to run a separate query to copy data to the newly created table.

I recommend using dumping mechanism instead: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html

`CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE original_table INCLUDING ALL);`

Comment: This wouldnt include the data?

Comment: @Martin INCLUDING ALL is an abbreviated form of INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING STORAGE INCLUDING COMMENTS.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtable.html @Martin

Comment: @dinindu: but this does not include the data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree, I didn't test this. Seems not including data. Martin you may better use pg_dump instead. Or after copy all, run a separate insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Dude!

2-line easy solution:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT * FROM existing_table
```